# flask create_all not creating imported tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

The two modules server.py and models.py are in the same directory. I import the models before running the create_all but the User table is never created. I have also tried changing `import models` to `from models import User` with the same result. Please help me understand what is going on here. 
Server.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from fileserver.filebutler import butler
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(butler)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://working_url'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


def initialize_db():
    import models
    db.create_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialize_db()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

models.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from downloadr import db


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    email = Column(String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name=None, email=None):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I removed the __tablename__ line from each modeled object and this did NOT solve my problem. For a solution I still search :).

Comment: It wasn't the removal of the tablename I was getting at, it was adding the 'db.' to the Column and type parts.

Comment: Also to check - the db user you specify in your connection has the right to CREATE TABLE

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
from models import *
```

It works fine in my case (i'm not using a function to init though, just 2 lines of code in the if clause).